# Google play intent for app review data

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

Is there any way to send data to Google Play intent with the review of the app and how many stars the app has?
I am taking user's review for the app in an `Edittext` view and on click of Submit button I want to pass that data to Google play so that the review bar is inflated with the edittext's text
Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Yeah, if you could do this then every app would post an automatic 5 star review from all their users.

Comment: Ohh, yeah !
I didn't think about that.
Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Google Play's guidelines it is not allowed since it can allow unfairly generated automatic reviews. Think an application that sends rating and review about itself without users' knowledge in the background.

Check rating and reviews guidelines here: https://play.google.com/about/storelisting-promotional/ratings-reviews-installs/

Check available Google Play intents here:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play.html#android-app